# JFrame program freezes when button is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, event-dispatch-thread

When the JButton is pressed the program will just freeze and the close button on the title bar will not close it and the only way to close it is with task manager.

Code for the button being pressed:

```java
class ClickButton implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent action ) {

        btn.setVisible(false);

        while(!btn.isVisible()) {
            label1.setText("Slaying Demons"); 
            wa(500);
            label1.setText("Slaying Demons.");
            wa(500);
            label1.setText("Slaying Demons.."); 
            wa(500);
            label1.setText("Slaying Demons..."); 
            wa(500);
        }
    }
}
```

The wa() method is just a simple thread.sleep() method that takes in the parameter for how long it should sleep.

Comment: You're never setting `btn.setVisible(true)` so the while loop could stop.

Comment: Do you understand what a loop is?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using a while loop that never closes. What your code does is it does the label.set(text) section and because it is in a loop it then does it again. Try using a if statement instead.